# PyQt5 - how to know which of the button is pressed

Tags: python, user-interface, button, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI that needs to look like a grid. It has 900 button that are created in a loop. Is there any way to determine which of the button was pressed?

```
    for i in range(30):
        for j in range(30):
            button = QPushButton()
            layout.addWidget(button, i, j)
```

So for example if a button is pressed on 25th row and 13th column I want to have a function that would print that the button (25,13) was clicked.

Comment: For a number that high, you may consider using QTableWidget instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can also use [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbuttongroup.html). It makes signal handling easier and has a custom ID per button.

Something like this:

```py
def makeButtons(self):
    n = m = 30
    self.group = group = QButtonGroup()
    group.setExclusive(False)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            button = QPushButton()
            id = i * m + j
            group.addButton(button, id)
    group.idClicked.connect(self.onIdClicked)

def onIdClicked(self, id):
    row, col = divmod(id, 30)
```

Comment: Note that `group.exclusive = True` makes sense only for PySide6 with the property feature enabled (something I normally advise against, but that's my opinion). The question is tagged for PyQt5, so it should be `group.setExclusive(False)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [QObject::ObjectName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#objectName-prop). This would allow you to set a name as a string for every button. Then you can `connect` every button to a slot that does something with that information.

Your code could look something like this. Note: This code is untested.

```
def makeButtons(self):
    for i in range(30):
        for j in range(30):
            button = QPushButton()
            button.setObjectName(f"Button {j}")
            button.clicked.connect(self.someSlot)
            layout.addWidget(button, i, j)

def someSlot(self):
    name = self.sender().objectName()
    print(name)
```

Comment: The code is missing the part where the object name is set, so it will always print an empty string.